Bitbucket / Symfony Project - Pipeline execution require driver on cache clear - No driver found running cache clear
I'm facing an issue while trying to setup a pipeline for symfony project, here is my pipeline code :
# Template PHP Build
# This template allows you to validate your PHP application.
# The workflow allows running tests and code linting on the default branch.

image: composer:2.5


pipelines:
  default:
    - parallel:
        - step:
            name: Test
            script:
              - composer install
              -  ./vendor/bin/phpunit test
            caches:
              - composer
        - step:
            name: Lint
            script:
              - composer install
              - ./vendor/bin/phplint . --exclude=vendor
              - vendor/bin/phpstan analyze -l 0 -c phpstan.neon . --memory-limit=1G
            caches:
              - composer

Here is the error :
Error thrown while running command "cache:clear". Message: "An exception occurred in the driver: could not find driver"

I've already had that issue when cloning my project on a new computer and trying to install composer, I've just add to comment a service that was called globally in my twig templates with this line in /config/twig.yml :
    globals:
        search_service: '@App\Service\SearchService'

Is there a way to avoid that issue without commenting or removing this line ?
